# Google Analytics Reporting API V4 Lifetime value requests - invalid dimensions/metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to make calls the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) and keep getting back unspecific error messages when trying to use certain dimensions and metrics. For example, I consistently get

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unknown dimension(s): ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

when passing `ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel`, despite it being [documented as a valid dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts&jump=ga_acquisitiontrafficchannel). Similarly, I get

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

when passing `ga:acquisitionSourceMedium` ([documented here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts&jump=ga_acquisitionsourcemedium)), even when not passing any metrics whatsoever.

Are the docs out of date? Is there some documentation elsewhere about valid combinations of dimensions and metrics?

Comment: "even when not passing any metrics" - you cannot query the API without specifying at least one metric (not that this has much to do with your problem).

Comment: would you mind posting the exact request you are making so that we can test it.  There is not enough information here to recreate the problem.   Please remember that V4 was only released 5 days while the documentation may still be incomplete I don't think there is much chance of it being out of date.

Answer (score 1):

All the [Lifetime Value reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6182550) and thus [`ga:acquisition...` dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#dimensions) are only valid for [App views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553#WebVersusAppViews) not web views.

Secondly the cohort/LTV dimensions can only be queried in within a [cohort requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohort_restrictions) for example:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
 "reportRequests": [
  {
   "viewId": "XXXX",
   "dimensions": [
    {
     "name": "ga:cohort"
    },
    {
     "name": "ga:acquisitionTrafficChannel"
    }
   ],
   "metrics": [
    {
     "expression": "ga:cohortSessionsPerUser"
    }
   ],
   "cohortGroup": {
    "cohorts": [
     {
      "name": "cohort 1",
      "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
      "dateRange": {
       "startDate": "2015-08-01",
       "endDate": "2015-09-01"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "cohort 2",
      "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
      "dateRange": {
       "startDate": "2015-07-01",
       "endDate": "2015-08-01"
      }
     }
    ],
    "lifetimeValue": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The error messages should probably be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well.  When I was in the Google Analytics Dashboard, I clicked on Acquisition->All Traffic->Channels and was fooled into thinking that I needed to combine the `ga:acquisitionMedium` dimension and `ga:newUsers` metric together.

[image]

[image]

When I clicked on `ga:acquisitionMedium`, it said that combining it with `ga:newUsers` was valid, despite the error that you mentioned in your question!  In reality, I just needed to combine `ga:medium` and `ga:newUsers` together.

I know this is not the exact query that you were doing, but here is an example of how I queried `New Users` count where the dimension `channel` equaled "organic" (note that I am forming the JSON request with Javascript and then using `JSON.stringify(req)` to send it):

```
var req = {
  reportRequests: [{
    viewId: '<Your Google Analytics view ID>',
    dimensions: [{ name: 'ga:medium' }],
    dimensionFilterClauses: [{
      filters: [{
        dimensionName: 'ga:medium',
        operator: 'EXACT',
        expressions: ['organic']
      }] 
    }],
    dateRanges: [{ startDate: '2019-11-01', endDate: '2019-11-30' }],
    metrics: [{ expression: "ga:newUsers" }]
  }]
};
```

The above query returns `5,654`, which is the same as seen in the "Acquisition" section of Google Analytics.

I definitely think the documentation and error message around this could be improved.